# How to determine what Class to deserialize XML into

Tags: c#, xml

I'm creating a parser that receives XML and deserializes it into object. I have used two different schemas to generate the classes that the XML is deserialized into.
However I need to determine what class to use when deserializing it.

The XML looks something like this:

Type A

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
 <typeA>
 <info>
 </info>
 </typeA>
```

Type B

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
  <typeB>
 <info>
  </info>
 </typeB>
```

How can this be done in a effecient way?

Comment: Are those XML files separate? If not, you shouldn't have a second XML declaration and you should wrap the `<typeA>...</typeA><typeB>...</typeB>` in another element.

Comment: Why dont you write the object type or Classname in your XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, serializers use namespaces to figure out what type to de-serialize the XML in to.

If you are implementing a custom serialization, I would follow the same convention.

You can retrieve namespaces from XML files, and then decide what type to deserialize it to.

Comment: But the namespaces isn't specified

Comment: @johan: Correct, you will need to add the XML namespace to the XML files. The "shortcut" way would be to use XPath to "test" your XML for presence of `typeA` or `typeB` element for decision criteria.

Comment: I get it as a string from a service. Then I would need to convert it into a XMLDocument? Isn't there another way?

Comment: If you get it as a `string` then you can simply test for it with `string.contains("></typeB>")` - which would be a pretty rare string to accidentally end up in your XML.